# How to get current CoreData item in onDelete

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

There two entities `Parent` and `Child`, which is one to many relationship. One Parent and many Child.

I use `EditMode` to delete `Child` data like:

```
@ObservedObject private var db = CoreDataDB<Child>(predicate: "parent")

var body: some View {

    VStack {
        Form {

            Section(header: Text("Title")) {
                ForEach(db.loadDB(relatedTo: parent)) { child in

                    if self.editMode == .active {
                        ChildListCell(name: child.name, order: child.order)
                    } else {
                        ...
                    }
                }
                .onDelete { indices in 
                  // how to know which child is by indices here ???
                  let thisChild = child // <-- this is wrong!!!

                  self.db.deleting(at: indices)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `deleting` method is defined in another Class like:

```
public func deleting(at indexset: IndexSet) {

    CoreData.executeBlockAndCommit {

        for index in indexset {
            CoreData.stack.context.delete(self.fetchedObjects[index])
        }
    }
}
```

And I also want to update other Attribute of `Parent` and `Child` Entities when `onDelete` occurs. **But I have to locate the current `Child` item which is deleted**. How to make it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible approach... (assuming your .loadDB returns array, but in general similar will work with any random access collection)

Tested with Xcode 11.4 (using regular array of items)

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Title")) {
                // separate to standalone function...
                self.sectionContent(with: db.loadDB(relatedTo: parent))
            }
        }
    }
}

// ... to have access to shown container
private func sectionContent(with children: [Child]) -> some View {
    // now we have access to children container in internal closures
    ForEach(children) { child in

        if self.editMode == .active {
            ChildListCell(name: child.name, order: child.order)
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
    .onDelete { indices in

        // children, indices, and child by index are all valid here
        if let first = indices.first {
            let thisChild = children[first]       // << here !!
            // do something here
        }

        self.db.deleting(at: indices)
    }
}
```

Comment: could you help me check the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62860449/crash-occurs-when-executing-share-extension-twice-in-system-files-to-share-file. It troubles me a long time. Thanks anyway.