# fetchRequest is null when calling second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, swiftui

The code is

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Item.fetchRequest()
print(request)
```

`Item` is an entity of Core Data.

The first execution is correct, but when execute it again error occurs `Thread 12: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`.

The following is logs:
[image]
[image]

This is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675297/nsmanagedobjectcontext-nil-when-calling-second-time), but with Object C. It says that defining `managedObjectContext` in view controller directly instead of transferring it from `AppDelegate` can fix the bug.

In my code, the `managedObjectContext` is in `SceneDelegate`.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let context = CoreData.stack.context
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
            .environmentObject(UserEnvironment())
    )
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

and

```
import CoreData

class CoreData: NSObject {
    
    static let stack = CoreData() 

    public var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        
        get {
            return self.persistentContainer.viewContext
        }
    }

    private lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
        
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "iCloud.com.xxxx")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let nserror = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        
        return container
    }()
}
```

Then how to fix the bug in Swift? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show code of `CoreData.stack`? I feel it is just destroyed, because local.

Comment: I have added the code and a demo project for reproducing the bug attached by link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the bug by change

`let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Item.fetchRequest()`

to

`let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>.init(entityName: "Item")`

Comment: This worked for me as well.