# Deleting CoreData from SwiftUI List with Sections

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, core-data, swiftui

### Goal

I want to delete an item from a `SectionedFetchRequest` on a `ForEach` inside a List. The only solutions I have found are for a regular `FetchRequest` I have managed to delete it from the UIList but not from the CoreData's `ViewContext`.

*My question is unique because I'm trying to delete from a SectionedFetchRequest which is different than a FetchRequest*

```
    @SectionedFetchRequest(entity: Todo.entity(), sectionIdentifier: \.dueDateRelative, sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Todo.dueDate, ascending: true)], predicate: nil, animation: Animation.linear)
    var sections: SectionedFetchResults<String, Todo>
```

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {      
                ForEach(sections) { section in
                    Section(header: Text(section.id.description)) {
                        ForEach(section) { todo in
                            TodoRowView(todo: todo)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                        }
                        .onDelete { row in
                            deleteTodo(section: section.id.description, row: row)
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
```

```
    func deleteTodo(section: String, row: IndexSet) {
        // Need to delete from list and CoreData viewContex.
    }
```

```
// My old way of deleting notes with a regular fetch Request
func deleteNote(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    for index in offsets {
        let todo = todos[index]
        viewContext.delete(todo)
    }
    try? viewContext.save()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete data from CoreData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68375431/delete-data-from-coredata)

Comment: @loremipsum Hmmm I'm not sure in my context how to utilize that answer as I am using a ForEach loop. I haven't seen a delete solution for a sectionedFetchRequest yet.

Comment: That answer is the most practical you can use `swipeActions` with that method. You can still use indexSet as you are but you have to do it for the array in the section. It does not work with all the objects.

Comment: @loremipsum tried that solution but what would I put in my context for the .onDelete ? I don't know what to pass into that function or access the todo.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is how you would use the link...

Add this to the `TodoRowView(todo: todo)`

```
.swipeActions(content: {
    Button(role: .destructive, action: {
        deleteTodo(todo: todo)
    }, label: {
        Image(systemName: "trash")
    })
})
```

And you need this method in the `View`

```
public func deleteTodo(todo: Todo){
    viewContext.delete(todo)
    do{
        try viewContext.save()
    } catch{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Or you can use your current setup that uses `onDelete` on the `ForEach`

```
.onDelete { indexSet in
    deleteTodo(section: Array(section), offsets: indexSet)
    }
```

That uses this method

```
func deleteTodo(section: [Todo], offsets: IndexSet) {
    for index in offsets {
        let todo = section[index]
        viewContext.delete(todo)
    }
    try? viewContext.save()
}
```

And of course for any of this to work you need a working

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
```

At the top of your file

Comment: It worked! Thanks again. the whole arrays and IndexSet portions is still confusing I guess I'll need to figure it out more.

Comment: @JustinComstock `onDelete` provides the set of index items (`indexSet`) that the user has selected to delete. When swiping it is only one but if you put an edit button on the `List` you can delete multiple items (that is why you need the loop). Each `section` has its own `ForEach`/array of `todo` items soneed to pass the array to delete it because you would have to search for the specific section.

Comment: I'm getting "NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 1 from section 0 which only contains 1 items before the update'" with the swipeActions solution when deleting the last item in a section. Not sure what's the reason. 

Comment: @abegehr no idea, I know this was common in early versions of SwiftUI and older versions of Xcode. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. you can include that in a question someone will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question when searching for a neat solution, couldn't find one so thought I'd share my attempt at deleting from a `@SectionedFetchRequest`.

```
  var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {      
                ForEach(sections) { section in
                    Section(section.id) {
                        ForEach(section) { todo in
                            TodoRowView(todo: todo)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                                .onDelete { indexSet in
                                    deleteTodos(section: section, offsets: indexSet)
                                }
                        }
                        
                    }

                }
            }
            ...

    private func deleteTodos(section: SectionedFetchResults<String, Todo>.Section, offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            
            offsets.map { section[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very neat! I like that it's similar to the original one.