# Issue separating out delete function for CoreData | SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

Essentially I have the following function that I am storing in a separate class called DataController where I handle saving, deleting, editing, etc. The issue is I am trying to pass the indexset over the to the function from the .onDelete modifier:

**Current Function**

```
func deletePackage(offsets: IndexSet, descriptor: Array<AnyObject>, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        offsets.map { descriptor[$0] as! NSManagedObject }.forEach(context.delete)
            try? context.save()
    }
```

Also getting the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type
> 'Optional<(IndexSet)-> Void>'
>
> Cannot convert value of type 'FetchedResults' to expected
> argument type 'Array'
>
> Cannot convert value of type 'IndexSet. Type' to expected argument
> type 'IndexSet'

**onDelete:**

```
.onDelete(perform: dataController.deletePackage(offsets: IndexSet, descriptor: packages, context: moc))
```

**Fetch Request & MOC:**

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var packages: FetchedResults<Packages>
@StateObject private var dataController = DataController()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting CoreData from SwiftUI List with Sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70399514/deleting-coredata-from-swiftui-list-with-sections)

Comment: No, I'm not talking about sections at all - I just need to separate out the function into its own file and am having trouble passing the parameters..please read my question

Comment: It’s the same function look at the answer. You haven’t provided anywhere near the code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: have you tried: `.onDelete { ndxSet in
     dataController.deletePackage(offsets: ndxSet, descriptor: packages, context: moc) }`