# How do remove nested list

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to swipe remove an item from an observable object who's array is nested within another array:

The structure looks like below and printed out and when a user swipes one of the items below I want to delete the item out of the observable object:

[image]

The data of the observable object  (when printed out) looks like this. And I'm trying to delete an item from the 'data' array but its within its own list newDataModelist

```
struct MockData: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let name, boat, time: String
    let isFavourite: Bool
   

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name = "Name"
        case boat = "Boat"
        case time = "Time"

    }
}
```

```
[nameofapp.newDataModelist
(
id: 1, 
date: "190623", 
data: 
[nameofapp.MockData(id: 1001, name: "Rich", boat: "RS Neo", time: "10102"), 
nameofapp.MockData(id: 1002, name: "Isla", boat: "RS Aero", time: "5903"), 
nameofapp.MockData(id: 1003, name: "Ben", boat: "RS Aero", time: "5843"), 
nameofapp.MockData(id: 1004, name: "Dar", boat: "RS Aero", time: "5783")
]
), 
nameofapp.newDataModelist(
id: 2, 
date: "190622", 
data: 
[nameofapp.MockData(id: 1005, name: "rach", boat: "RS Neo", time: "10102"), 
nameofapp.MockData(id: 1006, name: "sam", boat: "RS Aero", time: "5903"), 
nameofapp.MockData(id: 1007, name: "nigel", boat: "RS Aero", time: "5843"), 
nameofapp.MockData(id: 1008, name: "pete", boat: "RS Aero", time: "5783")],
)
]
```

Ive tried to delete the item using onDelete and the indexset array but it will print 1,2,3 which is right for the second array but as i need to delete the item from the observable object, I need to get its index from the first array as well , so in the format

```
.onDelete { indexSet in
                        for n in indexSet {
                        observeredObject.resultslist[x]data[n]

                      
                        }
```

```
List {
                
                ForEach( observeredObject.resultslist) { result in
                    
                    ForEach (result.data) {
                        res in
                        HStack {
                            Text(res.name)
                            Spacer()
                            Text(res.boat)
                            Spacer()
                            Text(res.time)
                        }
                    }.onDelete { indexSet in
                        for n in indexSet {
//                           var _ = print(n)
                      
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your explanation isn't easy to understand, the screenshot doesn't match the data sample and you mention different names for what seems to be the same array property. Could you please structure your question a bit better?

Comment: fair enough. thanks for your reply.  i've added the model as well so that may make things easier? i'm trying to understand once i swipe the delete how to then delete from  the observable object which is called resultslist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting CoreData from SwiftUI List with Sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70399514/deleting-coredata-from-swiftui-list-with-sections)

Comment: the issue is the observable object is an array whose has one of the items in that also an array (called data). so I cant use                                          

    for index in offsets {
        let removeitem = observedobject[index]
        managedObject.delete(removeitem)
    }
}. because the index is the data array (ie 0,1,2) and not the observed object that is also a list. so i need something like ie Observedobject.resultlist[firstindex].data[indexofitem]..