# Deleting CoreData object from a grouped (by Dictionaries) List in SwiftUI

Tags: dictionary, swiftui, core-data, delete-row

I have an issue with Swipe to Delete on a grouped List in that it randomly deletes the wrong object. I understand that this comes from the (grouped) Lists index not matching the index of the object in CoreData. Unfortunately I can't figure how to pass the correct index.

Does anyone have any hint in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance!

Here is my List View as well as my grouping function:

```
  ForEach(sectionDataCategory()) { section in
                        Section {
                            ForEach(section.notes) { note in
                                NavigationStack {
                                    NavigationLink {
                                        EditNotesView(projects: projects, note: note)
                                    } label: {
                                        Text(note.name ?? "")
                                    }
                                }
                            }.onDelete(perform: deleteNotes)
                        } header: {
                            Text(section.name )
                        }
                    }
```

```
  func sectionDataCategory() -> [NotesSection] {
        let dictByCategory = Dictionary(grouping: projects.notesArray, by: { $0.category })
        var completedSectionData = [NotesSection]()
        for key in dictByCategory.keys {
            completedSectionData.append(NotesSection(name: key ?? "", notes: dictByCategory[key]!))
        }
        return completedSectionData.sorted()
    }
```

```
    struct NotesSection: Identifiable, Hashable, Comparable {
        static func < (lhs: NotesListView.NotesSection, rhs: NotesListView.NotesSection) ->    Bool {
            lhs.name < rhs.name
        }
        
        var id: Int { hashValue }
        let name: String
        let notes: [Notes]
    }
```

I tried different approaches to figure the correct index like the firstIndex(where:) method. I'm at a point where I'm not sure if this would even work with CoreData

EDIT: As already pointed out in the comments I'm not using SectionedFetchRequests here. Notes here is a child of Projects Entity using a to-many relationship. The suggested solutions unfortunately won't work...

Comment: Probably not directly related, but I would suggest having the `NavigationStack` outside of **all** the `ForEach` loops.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting CoreData from SwiftUI List with Sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70399514/deleting-coredata-from-swiftui-list-with-sections)

Comment: Neither of the two versions work, I'm afraid, as I don't use SectionedFetchRequest. I should have pointed out that my Notes Entity is a child of my Projects Entity by using a to many relationship.

Comment: The reason I have the NavigationStack inside the ForEach is that this is a child viel. It's all incapsulated in a NavigationSplitView. I need the NavigationStack at that point in order to get the Navigationlink working. At least that's the only solution I got the whole think running - The new Navigation APIs came with a lot of headaches for me

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `@SectionedFetchRequest` for `Note` to group by section, you'll need to do a `@FetchRequest` per section with a predicate `"section = %@"` but that is inefficient:

```
let section: NoteSection
var notesRequest: FetchRequest<Note>(...
var notes: FetchedResults<Note> {
    notesRequest.wrappedValue.nsPredicate = NSPredicate("section = %@", section)
    return notesRequest.wrapepdValue
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. So you mean to delete an entry from a List that got grouped into different sections via a Dictionary, I should run another FetchRequest? This feels a bit too much overhead to only delete an object, as I don't have to go that route for deleting for an unordered or even an ordered List. Does grouping the list require so much more in term of identifying the correct object to delete? Again, thanks for your reply! I hope I can learn from this.

Comment: Yes it is overhead, that's why you should just used `@SectionedFetchRequest` for `Note` and it will do a SQL query that groups by section.